# duplicate video stream using a router (?)

Tags: router, streaming

I have a viedo stream coming from one site, I want to do the following with the minimum delay possible:

I want to duplicate the stream (inside the router - preferred) and send it to a few more locations one of them is local network and the rest - on other networks.

I want to be able to do it to several streams simultaneously.

Is it possible to do this - using network devices only ? What device is capable to do this ?

(I can always record the stream and rebroadcast it - but that's a lot of delay, I'm looking for functionality that similar to port duplicating, but on higher layers).

Thanks.

Comment: I take it you want to do this to save on bandwidth? 30 people all watching the same stream = 30 lots of data, rather than just one? There may be other ways around this (interim streaming server that does it on the fly with no delay)...

Comment: I have a high-cost line that I want to send the stream once to a central hub, and low-cost lines from the hub that I want to send it over to many sites.

Comment: What kind of stream is this? This cannot be done at network level for TCP streams, as the recipient participates in the session and TCP doesn't support multiple recipients. Unicast, unidirectional UDP RTP stream could be duplicated this way, though the proper way would to be just use multicast. Multicast is problematic in WAN, but should be no problem in a network where you have control on all equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Is the video stream sent using multicast? If so, it should be a "simple" matter of having additional recipients subscribing to the stream.

If it's sent using unicast, there is no simple answer, but I suspect a suitable concoction of routers using "static NAT mappings" in inbound ports, plus switches using port-duplication (to get as many copies of the stream you want), feeding the data stream to the router ports would be sufficient. However, I have not tested this and it may require one router (definitely one router port) per extra destination.

Comment: It should be unicast.